# Extend room owner kicking capabilities

Tags: feature-request, chat, kick-mute

I think that the (relatively) new room owner kicking capabilities are an invaluable moderation tool to replace flagging rings in most cases.

The current limitations say that a room owner cannot kick another user unless that user has spoken recently in the room. I would like to extend the limitation to allow kicking any user who has *interacted* in the room.

That mainly includes:

- Users who starred things in the room.
- Users who flagged things in the room (while being in the room).

And that to combat star spams.

Answer (score 2):

You can flag and star from the transcript, so this won't actually prevent any of those actions (unless the user doesn't know this).

To actually do something, your idea would have to be extended to prevent users from starring or flagging when kicked.

In the case of flagging, I also strongly believe that nobody except a moderator should be able to take that ability from a user. Flagging would be the primary way to deal with a rogue room owner, that option should always be available. And what I really don't want to happen is a bunch of room owners deciding who gets the flagging privilege in their room.

I don't care as much about stars, abuse can be annoying, but there should be better ways to prevent this (especially as you can't see who is starring unless they admit to it).

Comment: There are better ways, ideally, I wouldn't let a user star anything in the room unless he's been there speaking and participating for a reasonable amount of time. But this solution seems easier to develop === more likely to be implemented.

Comment: Everythings fine, except that _We can see who starred crap_.

Comment: Note that as of recently, it's no longer possible to publicly see who starred a particular message, so users can't be kicked for that reason.